WPF Main Window not showing after configuration selection in MVVM application
I have a minimal WPF MVVM application that shows a configuration selection dialog



and should then open a main window to display the selected configuration. However, the main window is not showing up after configuration selection.
The application flow should be:

Show configuration selection dialog
User selects a JSON file
User clicks OK
Main window opens showing the configuration

Currently, steps 1-3 work, but step 4 fails silently - the main window does not appear.
The relevant code is in this specific commit.
Key parts of the code:
// App.xaml.cs
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnStartup(e);

    // Show config selection window first
    var configWindow = new Views.ConfigSelectionWindow();
    var result = configWindow.ShowDialog();

    if (result == true)
    {
        var vm = (ViewModels.ConfigSelectionViewModel)configWindow.DataContext;
        var configPath = vm.SelectedConfigPath;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(configPath))
        {
            // Create and show main window with selected config
            var mainWindow = new Views.MainWindow(configPath);
            mainWindow.Show();  // Window doesn't show up after this line
        }
        // ...error handling
    }
}

The code just executes without showing the window.
Environment:

Visual Studio 2019 Professional
.NET Framework 4.8
Windows 10

What could be preventing the main window from showing up? How can I debug this further?
P.S. The issue was resolved by properly managing the application's ShutdownMode. Setting it to OnExplicitShutdown before showing the config dialog, then changing to OnMainWindowClose after creating the main window prevented premature application shutdown. Additionally, fixed a binding issue by changing XAML bindings to OneWay mode for read-only properties.
